# Telegram Bot: detect when user read message

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegraf.js

I am working on a telegram bot using telegraf JS.
My bot periodically sends messages to my users.
I would like to know when a user read a message my bot sent (on telegram app, there is small `v` on the bottom right corner of a message when I read the message).

Is there a way for my bot to detect this event ?

I did check Telegraf JS documentation but I did not find.

I use typescript, so I checked the function `bot.on` that takes a filter as first argument and a callback at second argument, for instance to capture user's message:

```
telegraf.on('text', (ctx) => console.log('Got a message !'));
```

I found possible filters (in `telegram-types.d.ts`):

```
export type UpdateType =
  'callback_query' |
  'channel_post' |
  'chosen_inline_result' |
  'edited_channel_post' |
  'edited_message' |
  'inline_query' |
  'message' |
  'pre_checkout_query' |
  'shipping_query' |
  'poll' |
  'poll_answer'

export type MessageSubTypes =
  'voice' |
  'video_note' |
  ...
```

Maybe there is one filter that corresponds to what I am trying to do but I don't find a documentation that explains what all this types correspond...

I did search for doc on this types here:

- https://telegraf.js.org/types/Types.UpdateType.html
- https://telegrafjs.org/#/?id=on

Comment: I did make a few bots but never heard about such a feature. I don't believe it is supported. if this is very important to you, you can make self-bot (using `gramjs`) which is harder to implement but you have full access to telegram Api (actually it has the official telegram api which is being used for non-official telegram versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, telegram bot api don't have this function